# How to deploy wso2 esb on websphere?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Is it possible to deploy WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 on websphere application server ?
Last example found on google is from 2008 ...
How is created the required war file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From WSO2 Carbon platform 4.0.0 release onwards WSO2 has dropped the official support for hosting WSO2 products on third party containers. So there is no official reference on how to run WSO2 products in third-party containers like WebSphere. One of the main reasons for this is the fact that the WSO2 Carbon container itself is secure enough for any enterprise deployment. Also when you run a server instance like WSO2 BAM, inside a third party container, the WSO2 product instance will be using its own ports etc.

Deployment on a third party container adds more complications, for e.g. the logging aspects are taken over by the container, the parser used is that of the container etc. This leads to additional complications when it comes to analyzing/debugging issues, as the model drastically changes from the usual native container based deployments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer.