# WSO2 ESB deploying on application servers e.g. WebLogic

Tags: deployment, wso2, weblogic, esb, wso2-esb

Is it possible to deploy WSO2 ESB on traditional Application servers like Weblogic? Or is expected to run standalone java application only.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be issues when you do so. You can find an answer with an explanation for a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522775/how-to-deploy-wso2-esb-on-websphere/33527243#33527243).