# Running WSO2 API Manager on Web Logic Server

Tags: java, weblogic, wso2-api-manager

API manager comes as package and embedded with Apache Tomcat. We want to run it on WebLogic server. Either it can be packaged with Embedded WebLogic server like Tomcat or we can create war out of it so that it can run in Tomcat or any other container.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This will be error-prone and not recommended. An explanation for a similar question can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522775/how-to-deploy-wso2-esb-on-websphere/33527243#33527243).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick anwser